# Fixed point problem

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $g \in C(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$ with $K > 0$ such that $|g(x) - x| \leq K$.

1. Is there a function g without a fixed point?
2. Is there a non-injective function g?
3. Is g always surjective?

ad 1.: for $n=1$, I think $g(x)=x+1$ might work:
$$g(x) - x = 1 =:K > 0 $$ but $g(x)$ obviously has no fixed point $g(x^*)=x^*$.

ad 2.: I think $g$ is always injective because the $\ker(g)$ is trivial.

ad 3.: No idea.

Comment: What does the $C$ in $C(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R^n)$ mean?

Comment: Let $g \in C(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$  means that g is a continuous function $g: \mathbb{R}^n -> \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: What is $\ker g$? You may not assume that $g$ is linear.

Comment: As to your second question, the answer is "yes". Consider the case $n=1$ and $K=100,$ we define $g:\mathbf R\to\mathbf R$ by $$g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lr}1,&|x|\leq1\\x,&|x|>1.\end{array}\right.$$ Then $g$ is a desired example.

Comment: @user88544 Your example is discontinuous at $x=-1$. However, you can modify this by choosing a non-injective continuous $h:[-1,1]\to [-1,1]$ with $h(\pm1 )=\pm 1$ and set $g(x)=x$ for $|x|\ge 1$ and $g(x)=h(x)$ for $|x|<1$.

Comment: @Jochen Thank you very much for pointing out my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I will discuss the last question. Without loss of generality, you can show that any $g$ with the stated properties has a zero: the equation $g(x)=y$ is reduced to $g(x)=0$ by translation.

Define $f(x)=x-g(x)$, so that $g(x)=0$ amounts to $f(x)=x$. In other words, you are looking for a *fixed point* of $f$. But your assumption says that $|f(x)| \leq K$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, so that $f \colon \overline{B(0,K)} \to \overline{B(0,K)}$. You can now use Brouwer's theorem to conclude.